# Java applet certificate on Mac

Tags: java, macos, authentication, applet, certificate

One of site's I visit has Java Applet, which must use certificate based authentication. I got this cert and added it to Java's key store(cacert) as well as to key chain of Mac.

When applet starts it offers to choose certificate for authentication from list - but this list is empty.

Does anybody know about this issue in Mac Os and Safari browser?

thank you

Comment: Does this question belong on SuperUser instead?

Comment: what do you mean? java has single cacert for all users....